# Add on-premise CockroachDB node to a cluster hosted in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cockroachdb, distributed-database

I'm planning to deploy a small Kubernetes cluster (3x 32GB Nodes). I'm not experienced with K8S and I need to come up with some kind of resilient SQL database setup and CockroachDB seems like a great choice.

I wonder if it's possible to *relatively easy* deploy a configuration, where some CockroachDB instances (nodes?) are living inside the K8S cluster, but at the same time some other instances live outside the K8S cluster (2 on-premise VMs). All those CockroachDB would need to be considered a single CockroachDB cluster. It might be also worth noting that Kubernetes would be hosted in the cloud (eg. Linode).

By *relatively easy* I mean:

- *simplish* to deploy
- requiring little maintenance

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's straight forward to do a multi-cloud deployment of CRDB. This is one of the great advantages of cockroachdb. Simply run the `cockroach start` command on each of the VMs/pods running cockroachdb and they will form a cluster.

See this blog post/tutorial for more info: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/multi-cloud-deployment/